# Strange behaviour/error when splitting one line of code into two lines in class

Tags: c#

I have one line of code like the following:

```
    private ProductList list = ProductList.GetProductList();
```

where ProductList is a serializable class with the static method GetProducList. If I put it like above everything works fine, but if I split the line into two lines, like the following:

```
    private ProductList list;
    list = ProductList.GetProductList();
```

then, if I put my mouse marker over list in the second row, I get the error "C#: Unknown type list". I also get the following errors when putting the mouse marker over GetProductList(); "C#: Unknown type GetProductList of 'MySolution.Library.ProductList'", "C#: Unexpected end of declaration", "C#: There already is another member named ''", and finally "C#: There already is another type named ''".

Any ideas?

Comment: Not strange at all, what you're doing is not valid C#.  See Ben's answer.

Comment: I've removed references to ASP.Net MVC from your post as unrelated. Feel free to edit/revert. Side note: there is no need for thank you notes in posts on SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Your right that it is nothing to do with asp.net MVC but now my answer looks a bit out of context ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the code but I suspect because of the private access modifier you have declared list as a field.  The first works because it is valid to declare and initialise a field in that way, however the second doesn't work becuase, well you can't.  Something similar to the second 2 lines of code would work fine in a method, but you can't use access modifiers on variables.

Below is valid

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private ProductList list = ProductList.GetProductList();
}
```

Below is not

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private ProductList list;
    list = ProductList.GetProductList();
}
```

Below is also valid:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        ProductList list;
        list = ProductList.GetProductList();
    }
}
```

You could also initialise the field in the constructor

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private ProductList list;
    public MyController()
    {
        list = ProductList.GetProductList();
    }       
}
```